# Display link if image is empty

Tags: php, cakephp

```
<div class="actions">
 <?php
    foreach ($images as $image):

        if ($image['Image']['img_file'] != null) {
            echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['Image']['img_file'], array('alt' => 'Gallery Image'));
            echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $image['Image']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $image['Image']['id']));
        }

        else {
            echo $this->Html->link(__('Add image', true), array('action' => 'add'));
        }
        endforeach;
        ?>
</div>
```

Hi, I wish to achive the following things: if the image is null, I want to show the link 'Add Image', else if there is image, I want to show the link 'Delete'. Using the above code, it does not seem to work. Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: why am I getting negative comments? Am I posting it wrongly?

Comment: Is this CakePHP? What does "it does not seem to work" mean? Do you get errors? Do you get the delete link always or never?

Comment: when i add an image, the delete link is visible. but when there is no image, the Add image link is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, when there are no images in the gallery you want to show an "add image" link. But when there are no images the array is empty so that loop never runs once. Maybe something like this:

```
if( !empty( $images ) ) {
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo $this->Html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['Image']['img_file'], array('alt' => 'Gallery Image'));
        echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $image['Image']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $image['Image']['id']));
    }
}
else {
    echo $this->Html->link(__('Add image', true), array('action' => 'add'));
}
```

Comment: how do i only show a particular image from a database? for example $image['Image']['test.jpg']